# Bot Framework emulator not posting to localhost after renaming my solution (500 error)

Tags: botframework

I created a Web App Bot in Azure with a basic template, downloaded the files and tested it with no problems on localhost with the Bot Framework Emulator.

However, once I renamed the solution/project/namespaces from the default `Microsoft.Bot.Samples.SimpleEchoBot` to `MyBotName`, the Bot Emulator received `500 - Internal Server Error`.

The solution builds and runs, and setting a breakpoint in the MessagesController shows that the Post method is never reached.

How do I fix this?

Comment: note: although there are many existing questions which are variations on this topic, none of them specifically address connecting to localhost only (forget Azure), and specifically after renaming your solution. I've spent the last 2 hours on this and none of the other questions or answers match the solution.

Comment: Well that was downvoted in under 30 seconds. Downvoter: please explain, and if you think this is asked/answered elsewhere please show me - I will happily delete this if so.

Comment: You may got this downvote due to the fact that without code, it's almost impossible to help. As you found in your reply, the problem was typically a local error that would not have been reproduced if we haven't build the project first before.

Comment: @NicolasR I disagree. This problem will occur regardless of the code: anyone who downloads a bot template from Azure and then renames it will have this problem. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3898. Having this question/solution on SO will save others lots of time, which is why I added it. (I knew the solution before I posted the question - I'm trying to help others here.) If I were to now add code to the question it will needlessly complicate things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GET request to localhost:[PORT]/api/messages (open that url in the browser) reveals the error message `Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'messages'`. It was somehow finding both the old messages controller (`Microsoft.Bot.Samples.SimpleEchoBot.MessagesController`) and the new one (`MyBotName.MessagesController`).

Solution: delete the `bin/` folder and re-build/run the project.